# UUIDgenerate() withn a s4 class produces the same uuid at each instance

Tags: r, uuid, r-s4

When I create a new instance of a `S4` class in R, I would like the newly created object to have a unique `id` field. I try to achieve it through `UUIDgenerate()` from the `uuid` package. The problem is that I obtain the same `UUID` at every new object instance :

```
library(uuid)
setClass("C",
   representation=representation(
   id = "character"
 ),
   prototype = prototype(
    id = UUIDgenerate(use.time = TRUE))
 )


new("C")
An object of class "C"
Slot "id":
[1] "1e07d7c2-2d71-11e6-b5e1-e1f59d8ccf09"

new("C")
An object of class "C"
Slot "id":
[1] "1e07d7c2-2d71-11e6-b5e1-e1f59d8ccf09"

new("C")
An object of class "C"
Slot "id":
[1] "1e07d7c2-2d71-11e6-b5e1-e1f59d8ccf09"
```

Calling `UUIDgenerate()` successively in the R command line produces different `UUIDS` each time.

Where do I go wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a very good solution from Ben Tupper on R-help list. Defining an "initialize" function solves the problem even more cleanly :

```
setMethod("initialize", "C",
      function(.Object){
          .Object@id = UUIDgenerate(use.time = TRUE)
          .Object
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that the call to `UUIDgenerate` is evaluated when you run the `setClass` statement rather than when you use the `new`.  It has nothing to do with `UUIDgenerate` per se - for example this class will behave the same based on `sys.time` alone:

```
setClass("D",
         representation=representation(
           id = "character"
         ),
         prototype = prototype(
           id = as.character(Sys.time()))
)
```

In order to get what you want you could write a function that creates objects of class "C" like so:

```
NewC<-function(){
  new("C", id=UUIDgenerate(use.time = TRUE))
}
```

This should create a new object of class "C" every time with a different UUID.